# Get kml-file using android resource path?

Tags: android

Hey, i have a problem, need some help with the path for the kml-file.
I want to get the path so i can use intent to open the kml-file. It works
when i get the the kml from the web, but not when i got it as a resource.

Thanks

```
 package test1.test;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;


public class test11 extends MapActivity {


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);



            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=android.resource://test1.test/"+R.raw.skikart));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code u can get the information from the kmal file

```
URLConnection c = mUrl.openConnection();
            c.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            c.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            Log.i("URL===", ""+mUrl);
            // write connection to file
            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            Log.i(TAG,"Root Element: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

Comment: I cant get the information, can you see anything wrong from the code? Thanks

Comment: url = new URL("android.resource://test1.test/skikart");
    URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
    int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30;
    c.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    c.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    Log.i("URL===", ""+url);
    
    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Log.i(TAG,"Root Element: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());